# fast code searching in a large number of git repositories

Tags: git, code-search

We have about 20000 git repositories and the number is increasing. Sometimes we want to find out which repositories have contained a keyword on any of its branches/tags. `git grep` works for one or several repositories, but it takes too much time in iterating over all the repositories.

Now we have [OpenGrok](https://oracle.github.io/opengrok/). But it works only for fixed revisions. Indexing a revision takes a lot of time.

Are there any solutions or tools? Thanks for any advice.

Comment: [SourceGraph](https://about.sourcegraph.com/) was spamming me trying to sell me their product. It claims to do what you want.